# Generator expressions and Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, iterator, google-cloud-datastore, generator

I'm trying to create an "iterator" for a web app (via GAE) that takes as input a "template" string, two integers (creating a range), and a list of words. The user will insert a "#" into the string where they want numbers to be iterated over and a "@" in the string where they want the words to be iterated over.

Inputs:

```
template string: "Person#Likes@"
starting integer: 1
ending integer: 3
list of words: "Apples, Bananas, Oranges"
```

Outputs:

```
Person1LikesApples
Person1LikesBananas
Person1LikesOranges
Person2LikesApples
Person2LikesBananas
Person2LikesOranges
Person3LikesApples
Person3LikesBananas
Person3LikesOranges
```

I want the output to show itself in a result text box when the user clicks a submit button titled "next" or something similar. The kicker is that I want the output to only display the items for Person1 when they click the button the first time. Then, the second time they click it, only the items for Person2 show up and so on.

I wrote a simple little Python program with a generator but I'm having trouble incorporating this into my Google App Engine app.

Here are my functions:

```
def g(f, text, lower, upper, list):
    for num in range(int(lower),int(upper)+1):
        yield f(text.replace('#', str(num)), list)

def f(text, list):
    for i in list:
        print text.replace('@', i)
```

And other code:

```
if text and lower and upper and words:  
    result = g(f, words, lower, upper, list)
    self.render_iterator(result=next(result))
```

(^This code returns "None" in my result text box when I fill in the other values but does recognize it as a generator expression when I do a little fiddling around)

Is there another way to do this that I am missing? Should I be utilizing GQL and the Google Datastore instead? Let me know if you need to see any more of my code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest figuring out how to do this outside App Engine first.  It's a very simple matter of programming, but if you have trouble figuring it out, trying to do in inside a web app is just torture.  Once you feel comfortable with the solution, you can apply it to App Engine.

Answer (score 0):

`f()` has no return value, and therefore returns `None`. You need to change

```
print text.replace('@', i)
```

to

```
return text.replace('@', i)
```

Comment: Now all I get is the list of words as output.

Comment: Not sure if this helps but I got this message in the GAE log:


WARNING  2012-06-02 03:26:54,550 py_zipimport.py:139] Can't open zipfile /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg-info: IOError: [Errno 13] file not accessible: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg-info'